# Unresolved reference when using updated version openApiGenerate

Tags: kotlin, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

After upgrading openapi, I am getting  `error: unresolved reference: isListContainer`

```
import org.openapitools.codegen.CodegenModel

class PropertyGeneralizer : CodegenAmender {
    override fun amendModels(models: List<CodegenModel>) {
        val generalizations = findGeneralizations(models)

        models.flatMap { it.vars }
                .forEach {
                    if (it.dataType in generalizations) {
                        it.generalizedType = "${it.dataType}View"
                    }

                    if (it.isListContainer && it.complexType in generalizations) {
                        it.generalizedType = "${it.complexType}View"
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

While the build is able to identify

```
it.complexType
```

I can see change in pojoVars.moustache in new version. But my package has also one - https://codefile.io/f/nu3tkooU7IcCzWrNmXwb.

I tried changing the moustache file,
adding

```
  {{#isListContainer}}
  public {{classname}} add{{nameInCamelCase}}Item({{{items.datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}Item) {
    if (this.{{name}} == null) {
      this.{{name}} = {{{defaultValue}}};
    }

    this.{{name}}.add({{name}}Item);
    return this;
  }

  public {{classname}} remove{{nameInCamelCase}}Item({{{items.datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}Item) {
    if ({{name}}Item != null && this.{{name}} != null) {
      this.{{name}}.remove({{name}}Item);
    }

    return this;
  }
  {{/isListContainer}}
```

as well in my file added isListContainer line extra:

```
{{! Adder for Generalized List types }}
    public {{classname}} {{vendorExtensions.x-list-adder-function-name}}({{{vendorExtensions.generalizedType}}} {{items.vendorExtensions.singleElementName}}) {
        if (this.{{name}} == null) {
            this.{{name}} = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        this.{{name}}.add({{items.vendorExtensions.singleElementName}}.as{{items.complexType}}
        this.{{name}}.add({{items.vendorExtensions.singleElementName}}.as{{items.isListContainer }}
());
        return this;
    }
```